# convert params array of numbers (a string) into an actual integer Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, parameters, int

I am sending an array (`"[1,3,44,2,0]"`) via an Ajax `PATCH` call, and it arrives as:

```
Parameters: {"ids"=>"[1,3,44,2,0]"}
```

To taint check, I am using the following line - in which the match anchors against the start and end of the string, and makes sure that there is at least one digit, or that the numbers are comma separated:

```
raise "unexpected ids #{params[:ids]}" unless params[:ids].match(/\A\[(\d+,)*\d+\]\z/)
```

And to make an actual integer array out of it, I am using the following approach (strip the brackets, split on comma, convert each string element to an integer):

```
irb> "[1,3,44,2,0]"[1...-1].split(',').map {|e| e.to_i}
 => [1, 3, 44, 2, 0]
```

Is there a better (simpler, cheaper, faster) way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
JSON.parse(params[:ids])
```

But I think you should check your Ajax call. It must be possible to pass the array not as a string.

Comment: Thank you! My bad! I just checked the Ajax call, and though I wanted to pass the array as an integer array, I was actually calling `JSON.stringify` on it. I totally forgot about that - and I did it because I read someone recommending that approach. Was that a bad recommendation (to `stringify`)?? Is there nothing wrong with just passing an array of integers?